# How to create a custom task in gradle to pack java and kotlin code to a jar?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

We have a multi modular setup and we are sharing some tests classes between the modules (mainly Fakes implementations). Our current solution (that you can find below) works just for classes written in Java, but we are looking at supporting also shared kotlin classes.

```
if (isAndroidLibrary()) {
    task compileTestCommonJar(type: JavaCompile) {
        classpath = compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac.classpath
        source sourceSets.testShared.java.srcDirs
        destinationDir = file('build/testCommon')
    }
    taskToDependOn = compileDebugUnitTestSources
} else {
    task compileTestCommonJar(type: JavaCompile) {
        classpath = compileTestJava.classpath
        source sourceSets.testShared.java.srcDirs
        destinationDir = file('build/testCommon')
    }
    taskToDependOn = testClasses
}

task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: taskToDependOn) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from compileTestCommonJar.outputs
}
```

How can I modify the `compileTestCommonJar` so it supports kotlin?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when saying *sharing some tests classes between the modules*? Are those actual tests or just classes to be used in tests of different projects?

Comment: just classes, fakes implementations to avoid the usage of mocks

Comment: So basically your tests depend on those classes? Why don't you compile those classes in an extra module and add this module as `testCompile` or `testImplementation` dependency to your other modules.

Comment: i already have too many modules,  and imo that would be a workaround. I already have a working solution using Java files... just want to make it more flexible by being able to compile Kotlin code too

Comment: Using a module for code reusability is not a workaround. Instead creating tasks manually and conditionally in Gradle builds is one.

Comment: I disagree, I do not see anything wrong having a test shared folder and publish it to my nexus repository with the test classifier, but I do not like the idea of growing from 20 modules to 40 just to create some fake implementations. I know I could also have a only one sort of fake module that would depend on the rest of the projects but I do not like it either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we do:

1. In the module with shared test classes, pack the `test` source set output into a jar

```
configurations { tests }
...
task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    baseName = "test-${project.archivesBaseName}"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

artifacts { tests testJar }
```

2. In a module that depends on the shared classes

```
dependencies {
  testCompile project(path: ":my-project-with-shared-test-classes", configuration: "tests")
}
```

PS: Honestly, I would prefer to have a separate Gradle module with common test classes as it's more explicit solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `task compileTestCommonJar(type: JavaCompile)` compiles .java files only because its the task of `JavaCompile` type.

There's `KotlinCompile` task aswell, so you would need to merge it, it basically works similary to `JavaCompile` but compiles .kt files only.

Said that i wouldn't use task system to share the dependencies across, i would use separate module and work with default `compileTestKotlin` and `compileTestJava` task's `outputs`

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'KotlinCompile' for project ':project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: You need to import it org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinCompile

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, but I am still getting issues: `Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'KotlinCompile'` I am pretty sure I tried this before creating the question, but thanks in any case for your suggestions

Comment: Actually I believe the import should be `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile`, not `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinCompile`.

Comment: @sschuberth how can i import `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile` idea seems to not be able to resolve that. any idea how to?

Comment: It probably depends on the version of Kotlin you are using, maybe for you the import from the `dsl` group is still correct.